# How to obtain smallest eigenvalues with Arnoldi iteration

Tags: eigenvalues, iterative-method, gmres

I understand that the Arnoldi iteration produces a basis which tends to include in its span the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues of large magnitude (hence the analogy between the last vector of the Krylov subspace, $A^{n - 1} b$, and the result of $n - 1$ iterations of power iteration method [made in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration)).

However, most solver implementations (for example [this](https://jutho.github.io/KrylovKit.jl/stable/)) allow for the user to choose between obtaining the eigenvalues of largest or smallest magnitude, or even the ones of smallest real part.

How would that be implemented?

Comment: A rather handwavy answer is already in the Wikipedia article: "To get the smallest eigenvalues of A, the inverse (operation) of A should be used instead. " How the action of the inverse of A should be implemented is an active research topic itself, but you can check Yousef Saad's Numerical Methods for Large Eigenvalue Problems. It is a little bit (9 years old) now and the literature shifted significantly. However, it is a good start.